# Java Operand and Operator Puzzle

Tags: java, operators

Which operators will always evaluate all the operands?

Select the two correct answers.

```
a. ||
b. +
c. &&
d. ? :
e. %
```

Operator + applicable on all but unable to find the second. Is here in option?

Comment: `%` modulas my guess..:)

Comment: See in the some manual precedence of operators.

Comment: I suggest that you go through each option and explain what you *believe* the behaviour to be.

Comment: I suspect the question is about short circuit behavior - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

Answer (score 4):

`+` and `%`, of course.

- `&&` will short-circuit if the first operand is `false`, so the second operand may not be evaluated.
- `||` will short-circuit if the first operand is `true`, so the second operand may not be evaluated.
- `? :` evaluates only the alternative that corresponds to the value of the expression before `?`; the other one is not evaluated.

Both `+` and `%`, on the other hand, must have both operands in order to compute their results - i.e. the sum or the division remainder.

Answer (score 1):

Operators: "+" and "%". There is one more '|' called Boolean OR, in this operator both left and right evaluated before the test.

Comment: | isn't mentioned in the question, and if you're trying to complete the picture there are several more.